# Search around a specific substring elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, morelikethis

I'm using "more like this" query to  search similar texts, built with templates, making most of the text useless for the query,
How could I tell to elasticsearch to focus on 50-100 terms around a substring like "Subject :", "Title :" If they appear in the field on which I'm performing the "more like this" query ?

Comment: It would be very useful to add a bit of code to your question, so we can better understand your problem and possibly come up with a solution.

Comment: Also, providing some examples (ideally including the code) of what you've already tried would result in others not coming up with solutions you've tested already

Comment: Well the whole query is too long for a comment, but it is centered around this mlt statement  
  
    "mlt": {  
        "fields": ["mp_annonce.search"],  
            "like": [  
                {  
                    "_index": "myindex",  
                    "_type": "mytype",  
                    "_id": 123456  
                }  
            ],  
            "max_query_terms": 50,  
    }  

Now, is it possible to (given a substring like "subject :") boost terms at a maximal distance of this substring (like the slop of a match_phrase) to be used in the mlt ?

Comment: I didn't tried anything for now, I searched in the doc, or tried to imagine how to do that outside of the mlt... but came with nothing.